# Error while retrieving Process Builder using workbench

Tags: deployment, process-builder, workbench

I am ending up with the below error when I try to retrieve Process builder (Flow) using workbench. 
"Entity of type 'Flow' named 'My_Process' cannot be found"

My Package.xml is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>My_Process</members>
        <name>Flow</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>My_Process</members>
        <name>FlowDefinition</name>
    </types> 
    <version>43.0</version>
</Package>
```

Could someone please point me on what/where I am doing a mistake?

Comment: Only `<types>
        <members>My_Process</members>
        <name>Flow</name>
    </types>` will work. Otherwise try : `<types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Flow</name>
    </types>`

Comment: I did the same thing. I tried without flow definition too, it did not work.

Comment: When I tried using `<types> <members>*</members> <name>Flow</name> </types>` in my org , it worked for me. It gave me all flows present in my org.

Comment: You can try with this : try appending version number from your `Flow Versions` after your flow name as : `<members>My_Process-1</members>`. e.g here `1` is your version number.

Comment: Already tried this as well, got the same error. :(

Comment: Figured it out, I think it was deployed with the name My_Process-11 by my  colleague. However it was showing just My_Process when checked the metadata in the workbench so was trying with this name. When I tried to retrieve all the Process builders it was actually with the name My_Process-11.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80918/discussion-between-sfdc-sk-and-kanikala).

Comment: @Kanikala - I will recommend that you provide the details as an answer, so that someone coming across this will be aware that this was resolved.